# Check for `nil` and set if it's `try` in a hash

Tags: ruby

I want:

```
{
  "CATTLE" => {"Heifers" => 647, "Cows" => 633, "Weaners" => 662, "Steers" => 653},
  "BULL" => {"Bulls" => 196},
  "SHEEP" => {"Rams" => 410, "Ewes" => 1629, "Wethers" => 1579, "Calves" => 1241, "Weaners" => 300}
}
```

To get that, I start with an empty `mobs = {}` hash, and then populate it as I loop. If the key is `nil`, I set it and then populate it. I was wondering if there was a nicer way to do as below:

```
mob_livestock_group_response.each do |livestock_group|
  mobs[livestock_group['assetType']] = {} unless mobs[livestock_group['assetType']]
  mobs[livestock_group['assetType']][livestock_group['subtype']] = 0 unless mobs[livestock_group['assetType']][livestock_group['subtype']]
  mobs[livestock_group['assetType']][livestock_group['subtype']] += livestock_group['size']
end
```

Comment: What is `mob_livestock_group_response`?

Comment: a response object from an api call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write:

```
mob_livestock_group_response.each do |livestock_group|
  mobs[livestock_group['assetType']] ||= {}
  mobs[livestock_group['assetType']][livestock_group['subtype']] ||= 0
  mobs[livestock_group['assetType']][livestock_group['subtype']] += livestock_group['size']
end
```

Furthermore I would write this like this:

```
mob_livestock_group_response.each do |livestock_group|
  type = livestock_group['assetType']
  sub  = livestock_group['subtype']
  size = livestock_group['size']

  mobs[type]      ||= {}
  mobs[type][sub] ||= 0
  mobs[type][sub] += size
end
```